# Provide shortcut for searching posts of type questions or answers

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, search

It would be nice to have a shortcut for searching post of type question (`is:question`) or answers (`is:answer`) to reduce typing.

See also search for my post by using `user:me`.

I would suggest `is:q` for **questions** and `is:a` for **answers**.

Comment: That was a fast downvote.

Comment: Somebody doesn't want a shortcut.

Comment: Note that downvotes mean disagreement on meta. I don't think theres that much difference between `is:question` and `is:q`. I'd prefer a GUI for search rather than linking one syntax to another. I imagine the search for the non-techy users of the non-techy sites is not easy-to-use.

Comment: No need to shortcut anything to save a few keystrokes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn't *hurt* us to support this...so if we can make life easier, why not?

Sure, it'll be in the next build...`is:q` and `is:a` will be supported in addition to the full `is:question` and `is:answer` versions.  These are a power-user feature to begin with, any time we can shave off common activities is a good thing, given there's no downside to doing so.

Comment: Is "Add links to filter by questions only or answers only" which takes their current query and just links to the version with "is:question" or "is:answer" worth a new feature request? It's pretty much a shortcut

Comment: @random - I'm on little sleep so not parsing that correctly, can you rephrase?

Comment: On the sidebar, "Show only questions" and the link takes the current query, but The System adds "is:question" to it. Same for "Show only answers matching your search" Helps them learn the tricks if they see what happens when you want to drill down like that

Comment: @random - we've considered a full UI for search options before, it may be something we play with later...focus has shifted to the server move in NYC this weekend for the moment though.